# Php script to write and read word and byte

Tags: php, cpu-word, byte

I have an eeprom that I control with a php script. 
I can control the parameters of this eeprom reading and writing words (16 bit), some of these can control two different parameters with the possibility to write the first or the second byte (8 bit) of the word with a decimal o hexadecimal data.
There is a method to write a word (with the possibility to write the first or the second byte free) in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`pack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php):

```
// Unsigned decimal values of the bytes
$firstOctet = 125;
$secondOctet = 213;

$byte = pack('C', $firstOctet);
$word = pack('C*', $firstOctet, $secondOctet);
```

You'll probably need to supply values of the integer type to `pack()`, if you want to represent them in your code as Hex you can do one of the following:

```
// Both of these are identical to "$firstOctet = 125;"
$firstOctet = 0x7D;
$firstOctet = hexdec('7D');
```

Alternatively, you can declare literal Hex bytes in a string using this syntax:

```
// These should produce the same results as the pack() example
$byte = "\x7D";
$word = "\x7D\xD5";
```

If you need to convert the bytes you are reading back into integers for processing, you can use the complementing function [`unpack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php):

```
$word = "\x7D\xD5";
$bytes = unpack('C*byte', $word);
print_r($bytes);
/*
  Array
  (
      [byte1] => 125
      [byte2] => 213
  )
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for the clarity but I have a problem using these code. If I write the decimal code it runs, if I write the hexadecimal code like your second block of code it runs but if I write '$byte = "\x7D";' or with two hexa it returns this error: expects parameters to be long.
At the end if I try with the pack function it returns that one arguments is unused. Thanks for the patiences.

Comment: @Kerberos Sorry I wasn't very clear with that, if you use `"\x7D"` syntax, you *don't* need to use `pack()`, you are declaring a literal byte in a string. See [this example](http://codepad.org/AJUgc0cr), hopefully it should clarify a bit. Maybe [this](http://codepad.org/OEbz7VZE) will also help illustrate what the syntax means.

Comment: I think I found the problem! In the help of the pack function I find this lines: "it would be 8 bytes long: 4 bytes for the length (since it’s a 32bit value), 3 bytes for the ascii ‘aBc’, 1 byte for cr and 1 byte for lf", it converts the data in a string!
Therefore it occupies two words for 8 bytes of data, not one only word.
Hence the error of the "expected parameter to be long".
how do I put two hexadecimal (or integer) in a single word?

Comment: That's what `C*` does, it converts the supplied integers to 8-bit unsigned integers - basically bytes. What data do you have, and what do you want the binary to look like?

Comment: But with this parameter it returns:"help() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /htdocs/index10.php on line 4".
Where help() is the function where I put the word in the second parameter.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for the function?

Comment: I solved it by converting the decimal in binary with the 'decbin()' function and then combining the two string of binary number in one string 16 bit long.
Thanks for all.